# React app SSL error: EVP_DecryptFinal_ex bad decrypt

Tags: reactjs, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I am trying to run my React application with SSL certificate configured.
In my start.js file I specified key and cerificate paths like this:

```
const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, {
      ...serverConfig,
      https: {
        key: fs.readFileSync('./script/server.key', 'utf8'),
        cert: fs.readFileSync('./script/server.crt', 'utf8'),
        passphrase: 'XXX'
      }
    });
```

When I try to run the application, I'm getting an error:

```
error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! appname@0.1.0 start: `set HTTPS=true&&react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the appname@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried some of the potential solutions I found there:

```
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1411
```

but none of them worked for me.

What else can I do to configure it properly and run my application?